# what is 'this' doing out here relativelayout lyt=new relativelayout(this)

Tags: java, android

```
 Relativelayout lyt = new Relativelayout(this)
```

what is 'this' doing out here.
 is that the 'this' keyword in java,if yes what's happening behind the scenes.
 i just want how are we using 'this' keyword here

Comment: Hint: you are just beginning to learn java/android. Keep in mind: zillions of people have been there before you. They probably had the *same* questions that you have right now. So, please: do some research before putting up a *new* question. Chances are: everything you can dream of asking at this point has been asked. Here. Elsewhere. Countless times. And Answered.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, `this` means current object i.e. object you are currently working with.

When you say `Relativelayout lyt=new Relativelayout(this)` basically you are passing your current object while creating an object of `Relativelayout` (of course as long as `Relativelayout` has a contructor which accepts whatever is the type of `this`).

As an aside, you cannot use `this` in static context.

See below sample code with comments for explanation so it will be very easy for your to understand.

```
public class Class1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Class1().test(); // see here I couldn't do "Class2 class2 = new Class2(this);" because "this" cannot be used in "static" context, so I had to create an object of Class1
    }

    private void test() {
        Class2 class2 = new Class2(this); // here this means current object of "Class1"
    }
}

public class Class2 {
    private Class1 class1;

    Class2(Class1 _class1){
        this.class1 = _class1; // here "this" means the object of Class2.
    }
}
```

And finally for your question about keyword, yes "this" is a keyword in Java, refer JLS specs for complete list [(§3.9)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html), 'this' is the context. I guess this code line is on a class which extends activity, so 'this' represent the activity in which you want to insert the new layout.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the **Context** class is when creating a view dynamically in an activity.

For example, you may want to dynamically create a ** RelativeLayout** from code. To do so, you instantiate the ** RelativeLayout** class. The constructor for the **RelativeLayout** class takes a **Context** object, and because the Activity class is a subclass of **Context**, you can use the this keyword to represent the Context object.